# Published application requires visual studio to run

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, publish

I have developed a WPF application and I need to try it on other computers.

1- I change my project properties to build in release mode and rebuilt project. However, /bin/release folder is empty and it still generates /bin/debug folder.

2- I selected publish and install it on other computers. Funny thing is, the program is not running if that computer does not have Visual C# (.Net Framework, Sql server etc. does not cause a problem)

3- I added a installer and add project output(release) to this application. It says /bin/release/abc.exe couldn't be find.. Changed it to project output(debug) and it builds fine. However, this setup is not even working on my computer..

So my question is simple... How can I publish WPF application in release mode and how can I run them on other computers without installing Visual C#. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Check properties of your project, and set output folder for Release configuration.
2. You need .NET 4 framework installed on PC, to run (simple) WPF application.
3. Should work, when you set your output folder, see 1.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Target computers have .NET Framework 4, but it is still not working if it does not have Visual Studio. (It runs if I install Visual Studio, but after I uninstall only Visual Studio, it refuses to run again). Therefore, I assumed maybe debug mode publish requires Visual Studio to run, I could finally make a publish in release mode (I also need to change solution properties with project properties). It runs on other computers, but MSI is not working now